# HTML Links Aren't Working

Tags: html, css

I essentially have two problems. The first being that my links to each of my web pages do not work. I used intellisence to select the URL for the page files so I am not sure why I keep getting a "resource cannot be found" error when I run the solution and click on the links. The second problem is that I am trying to create my first responsive website. I am currently working on modifying the navigation menu so that when the screen goes below a specific width, it changes to being combined into a single dropdown menu (with styles to make it look good). I am using open source script to run the change. The script file is called responsivemobilemenu.js.

This is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Atlas Web Pages</title>
        @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
        <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/knockout-2.1.0.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/responsivemobilemenu.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="box-effect">
            <header id="header">
                <div class="web-header">
                    <div class="logo-image">
                        <img style="vertical-align:top" src="~/Images/WebPageLogo.png" height="85" width="820" alt="Atlas Logo" />
                        <br />
                    </div>
                    <div id="follow-icons">
                        <a href ="www.facebook.com/jmilam90"><img src="~/Images/FBIcon.png" alt="Follow on Facebook" height="40" width="40" /></a>
                        <a href ="www.twitter.com/jmilam900"><img src="~/Images/TwitIcon.png" alt="Follow on twitter" height="40" width="40" /></a>
                        <a href ="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCCSdkWipauQ1mhzEPAJfOnA"><img src="~/Images/YTIcon.png" alt="Subscribe on Youtube" height="40" width="40" /></a>
                        <a href ="mailto:jmilam90@gmail.com"><img src="~/Images/GMailIcon.png" alt="Send me an Email" height="40" width="40" /></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </header>
            <div class="rmm">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="~/Views/Home/Index">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="~/Views/About/About">The Team</a></li>
                    <li><a href="~/Views/Current/CurrentList">Current Line-Up</a></li>
                    <li><a href="~/Views/Retired/RetiredList">Retired Equipment</a></li>
                    <li><a href="~/Views/Tournament/TourneyInfo">Tournaments</a></li>
                    <li><a href="~/Views/Video/Videos">Videos</a></li>
                    <li><a href="~/Views/Sponsor/Sponsors">Sponsors</a></li> 
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div id="body-content">
                @RenderSection("featured", required: false)
                <section class="content-wrapper clear-fix">
                    @RenderBody()
                </section>
            </div>
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
        @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

this is the css for the menu:

```
.rmm {
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0 auto !important;
    text-align: center;
    line-height:19px !important;
}
.rmm * {
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color:transparent !important;
    font-family:Arial;
}
.rmm a {
    color:#ebebeb;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.rmm .rmm-main-list, .rmm .rmm-main-list li {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
.rmm ul {
    display:block;
    width:auto !important;
    margin:0 auto !important;
    overflow:hidden;
    list-style:none;
}


/* sublevel menu - in construction */
.rmm ul li ul, .rmm ul li ul li, .rmm ul li ul li a {
    display:none !important;
    height:0px !important;
    width:0px !important;
}


.rmm .rmm-main-list li {
    display:inline;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px !important;
}
.rmm-toggled {
    display:none;
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    margin:0 auto !important;
}
.rmm-button:hover {
    cursor:pointer;
}
.rmm .rmm-toggled ul {
    display:none;
    margin:0px !important;
    padding:0px !important;
}
.rmm .rmm-toggled ul li {
    display:block;
    margin:0 auto !important;
}

/* GRAPHITE STYLE */

.rmm.graphite .rmm-main-list li a {
    display:inline-block;
    padding:8px 30px 8px 30px;
    margin:0px -3px 0px -3px;
    font-size:15px;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 1px #333333;
    background-color:#444444;
    border-left:1px solid #555555;
    background-image:url('../rmm-img/graphite-menu-bg.png');
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
}
.rmm.graphite .rmm-main-list li a:hover {
    background-image:url('../rmm-img/graphite-menu-bg-hover.png');
}
.rmm.graphite .rmm-main-list li:first-child a {
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 6px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 6px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 6px;
    border-top-left-radius: 6px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
}
.rmm.graphite .rmm-main-list li:last-child a {
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 6px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 6px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 6px;
    border-top-right-radius: 6px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
}
.rmm.graphite .rmm-toggled {
    width:95%;
    background-color:#555555;
    min-height:36px;
    border-radius:6px;
}
.rmm.graphite .rmm-toggled-controls {
    display:block;
    height:36px;
    color:white;
    text-align:left;
    position:relative;
    background-image:url('../rmm-img/graphite-menu-bg.png');
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    border-radius:6px;
}
.rmm.graphite .rmm-toggled-title {
    position:relative;
    top:9px;
    left:15px;
    font-size:16px;
    color:white;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 1px black;
}
.rmm.graphite .rmm-button {
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    right:15px;
    top:8px;
}

.rmm.graphite .rmm-button span {
    display:block;
    margin-top:4px;
    height:2px;
    background:white;
    width:24px;
}
.rmm.graphite .rmm-toggled ul li a {
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    background-color:#555555;
    text-align:center;
    padding:10px 0px 10px 0px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #333333;
    border-top:1px solid #777777;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 1px #333333;
}
.rmm.graphite .rmm-toggled ul li a:active {
    background-color:#444444;
    border-bottom:1px solid #444444;
    border-top:1px solid #444444;
}

/* MINIMAL STYLE */

.rmm.minimal a {
    color:#333333;
}
.rmm.minimal a:hover {
    opacity:0.7;
}
.rmm.minimal .rmm-main-list li a {
    display:inline-block;
    padding:8px 30px 8px 30px;
    margin:0px -3px 0px -3px;
    font-size:15px;
}
.rmm.minimal .rmm-toggled {
    width:95%;
    min-height:36px;
}
.rmm.minimal .rmm-toggled-controls {
    display:block;
    height:36px;
    color:#333333;
    text-align:left;
    position:relative;
}
.rmm.minimal .rmm-toggled-title {
    position:relative;
    top:9px;
    left:9px;
    font-size:16px;
    color:#333333;
}
.rmm.minimal .rmm-button {
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    right:9px;
    top:7px;
}

.rmm.minimal .rmm-button span {
    display:block;
    margin:4px 0px 4px 0px;
    height:2px;
    background:#333333;
    width:25px;
}
.rmm.minimal .rmm-toggled ul li a {
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    padding:10px 0px 10px 0px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #dedede;
    color:#333333;
}
.rmm.minimal .rmm-toggled ul li:first-child a {
    border-top:1px solid #dedede;
}
```

Comment: To any external website the link must start with `http://` or `https://`. Otherwise the url is seen as relative to the current domain you're on. You can visualize this by clicking a link to see the error page, now look at the url. It should be something like `http://yourdomain.com/www.facebook.com/jmilam90` which is not facebook.

Comment: can you try to change your views urls into helpers like this Url.Action("someaction", "somecontroller", new { id = "123" }), this will help you make sure that you are getting the right URL for the site resolved, you can even replace the whole anchor with HTML.ActionLink(...), which will generate the whole link with URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
 <li><a href="/Home/Index">Home</a></li>
 <li><a href="/About/About">The Team</a></li>
 <li><a href="/Current/CurrentList">Current Line-Up</a></li>
 <li><a href="/Retired/RetiredList">Retired Equipment</a></li>
 <li><a href="/Tournament/TourneyInfo">Tournaments</a></li>
 <li><a href="/Video/Videos">Videos</a></li>
 <li><a href="/Sponsor/Sponsors">Sponsors</a></li>
```

You should consider using Html Helper.

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Link Text", "Action Name", "Controller Name")
```

Comment: I changed everything to Html.ActionLink and now they all work.